# Type systems of functional object-oriented languages

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, ocaml

I would like to know how exactly modern typed functional object-oriented languages, such as Scala and OCaml, combine parametric polymorphism, subtyping and other their features.

Are they based on [System F<sub><:</sub>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F-sub), or something stronger, or weaker?

Is there a well-studied formal type system, like [System F<sub>C</sub>](http://research.microsoft.com/~simonpj/papers/ext-f/fc-tldi.pdf) for Haskell, which could serve as a "core" for these languages?

Comment: For scala I know there's a formal system underlyng the language, I can't remember if it's vObj. Still I found a useful paper from A.Moors [here](http://adriaanm.github.io/files/scalina-final.pdf), but I can't tell its date

Comment: FYI: The paper was published at FOOL'08

Comment: Also see the paper about Scala's dependent object types: http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~amin/dot/fool.pdf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### OCaml

The "core" of OCaml type theory consists of extensions of System F,
but the module system corresponds to a mix of F<sub><:</sub>
(modules can be coerced into stricter signature by subtyping) and
Fω.

In the core language (without considering subtyping at the
module level), subtyping is very restricted in OCaml, as subtyping
relations cannot be abstracted over (there is no
bounded quantification). The language emphasizes polymorphic
parametrism instead, and in particular even the "extensible" type it
supports use row polymorphism at their core (with a convenience layer
of subtyping between closed such types).

For an introduction to type-theoretic presentations of OCaml, see the online book by Didier Remy, [Using, Understanding, and Unraveling the OCaml Language (From Practice to Theory and vice versa)](http://gallium.inria.fr/~remy/cours/appsem/) . Its [further reading](http://gallium.inria.fr/~remy/cours/appsem/ocaml-reading.html) chapter will give you more reference, in particular about the treatment of object-orientation.

There has been a lot of work on formalizations of the module system part; arguably, the ML module systems do not *naturally* fit Fω or F<sub><:</sub><sup>ω</sup> as a core formalism (for once, type parameters are *named* in a module system, instead of being passed by position as in lambda-calculi). One of the best explanations of the correspondence is [F-ing modules](http://www.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/f-ing/), first published in 2010 by Andreas Rossberg, Claudio Russo and Derek Dreyer.

Jacques Garrigue has also done a lot of work on the more advanced features of the language (that cannot be summarized as "just syntactic sugar over system F"), namely Polymorphic Variants (equi-recursives structural types), labelled arguments, and GADTs). Various descriptions of these aspects can be found [on his webpage](http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~garrigue/), including mechanized proofs (in Coq) of polymorphic variants and the relaxed value restriction.

You should also look at the webpage [A few papers on Caml](http://caml.inria.fr/about/papers.en.html), which points to some of the research article around the OCaml language.

### Scala

The similar page for Scala is [this one](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/143#papers). Particularly relevant to your question are:

- [A Core Calculus for Scala Type Checking](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/odersky/mfcs06.pdf), by Vincent Cremet, François Garillot, Sergueï Lenglet and Martin Odersky, 2006
- [Generics of a Higher Kind](http://adriaanm.github.com/files/higher.pdf), by Adriaan Moors, Frank Piessens, and Martin Odersky, 2008

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I'll keep the question open for a little more, though.

Comment: There's also an ongoing effort here at EPFL to formalize the foundation of Scala. Read more at https://github.com/namin/dot.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneBurmako for the reference, that's interesting work indeed!